# phalconphp for loop with numeric on volt

Tags: for-loop, long-integer, phalcon

Help to fix my code in phalconphp with volt I think so long

```
{% for casing in casings %}
   {% set i = 0 %}                              
   {% for case in cases if case.casing == casing.type %} //it have 4 loop but cases length is 20
       {% set i += 1 %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if i == 0 %}
       No values set
   {% else %}
       <ul>
   {% for case in cases if case.casing == casing.type %} // it repeat twice in my code
       <li> {{ case.description }} - {{ case.value }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
       <ul>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I know have loop.length, loop.index in for loop but when I use if in loop it have not number I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for casing in casings %}
     {% if loop.first %}
         <ul>
     {% endif %}
     {% for case in cases if case.casing == casing.type %}
         <li> {{ case.description }} - {{ case.value }} </li>
     {% endfor %}
     {% if loop.last %}
         <ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        No values set
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% for casing in casings %}
     {% if loop.first %}
         <ul>
     {% endif %}
     {% for case in cases if case.casing == casing.type %}
         <li> {{ case.description }} - {{ case.value }} </li>
     {% endfor %}
     {% if loop.last %}
         <ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        No values set
{% endfor %}
```

Thankyou for supported